# Python PILlow - Image.paste - TypeError: color must be int or tuple

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I would like to write a quick python script to assemble some rendered tiles into one image.
The tiles are 300x200 pixel RGB PNG files with the name of LG_Test.i.j.png where i is for the width of the image and j is for the height. The combined image size is 4200x1200 pixels.
I wrote the following script:

```
    import PIL
    from PIL import Image
    composed_image = Image.new('RGB', (4200, 1200))
    i = 0
    j = 0
    counter_i = 0
    counter_j = 0
    while j <= 1200-200:
        while i <= 4200-300:
            #Create File Name: name.i.j.png
            filename = "LG_Test." + str(counter_i) + "." + str(counter_j) + ".png"
            image_in = [Image.open(filename)]
            composed_image.paste(image_in, box=(i,j,300,200))
            i = i+300
            counter_i = counter_i+1
        i = 0
        j = j+200
        counter_i = 0
        counter_j = counter_j+1
    composed_image.save("Composed_Image.png")
```

When I try to run this script I get the following error:

```
composed_image.paste(image_in, box=(i,j,300,200))
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1740, in paste
self.im.paste(im, box)
TypeError: color must be int or tuple
```

The Composed image is RGB and the tiles are also RGB images.
I don't understand where the problem is.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: `image_in` is a `list`, not sure why you did that.

Comment: The first parameter you're passing to `.paste()` is a list (containing an image) rather than the image itself.  A list *is* valid there, but only if it contains integers (it gets interpreted as a solid color to paste).  Get rid of the square brackets in the assignment to `image_in`.

Comment: In your own words: where the code says `image_in = [Image.open(filename)]`, exactly what do you think this means? Specifically, what effect do you expect the `[]` to have?  Now, according to the documentation, what should be passed when calling `composed_image.paste`? Does `image_in` meet that description?

Comment: Does this help? `composed_image.paste(image_in, box=i,j,(300,200))`

Comment: I think `i` and `j` in the filename are the x and y position offsets, rather than the width and height.

Comment: This is exactly what happens if you have to solve a problem for which you have no training or education... :-) Thanks MarkRansom, jasonharper, KarlKnechtel. I copied code from a different solution (where the name was out of a list) and forgot to get rid of the square brackets... and looked at it for hours without seeing the mistake.

Comment: There's a one-liner to do it in the Terminal without any Python, using **ImageMagick** if you are interested.